# Confused on how to use || and && in the same if statement. Can anyone spot the problem?

Tags: java, string

I am confused on how to use `||` and `&&` in the same if statement.

What I am trying to do is have it print something if the string starts with an `"D"` or an `"O"`, and if one is true check if the string has a character length of two.

Example: if the string is `"DE"` it will print something. However, if it is `"SE"` it will not print anything.

```
else if( (answer.startsWith("D") || answer.startsWith("O")) 
            && (answer.length() == 2) ) {
 //print something
}
```

Comment: Your logic looks correct to me.  What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Note that you may also use `"DE".matches("[DO].")` as a shortcut here.

Comment: It could be that it's not branching into the `else if` part. Are you sure your main `if` condition is failing?

Comment: It all depends upon what the initial **IF** statement condition might be as to whether or not your **ELSE IF** will be checked. If the initial **IF** statement condition is true then your **ELSE IF** will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Java is applying a "short circuit" to your logic. It does the first part (starts with "D" or "O") and if that's true it proceeds to the second part (length is 2). However if the first part evaluates to false then it never even bothers to execute the second part.

So your "SE" string will never go into the "print something" bit because it doesn't meet your first criteria of starting with D or O. And based on your description of what the logic should be, that is correct.

If you actually mean that if it starts with "D" or "O" **OR** is 2 characters long then your logic statement should have been:

```
else if( answer.startsWith("D") || answer.startsWith("O") 
        || (answer.length() == 2 ) {
 //print something
}
```

Edit: Oops, just pasted the original code in the first time...!

Answer (score -1):

I would check first the length and after the two conditions e.g.

```
else if (answer.lenght()==2) {
     if (answer.startsWith("D") || answer.startsWith("O"){
      //print something that lenght is 2 and starts with D or O
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Changing the order of execution won't change the result in this case, and the additional nesting doesn't do anything apart from potentially limit the compiler from making optimisations such as short circuiting logic.

Answer (score -2):

In that case you have to check length first because && will true if left side and right side both true

```
else if( (answer.length() == 2)&&(answer.startsWith("D") || answer.startsWith("O"))
{
 //your logic 
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you are saying this.  The `startsWith` tests won't fail if you do them first, and the `length` tests won't fail if you do them second.